# Woocommerce Export Orders with Order Item Meta

Tags: plugins, export

I have this plugin http://docs.woothemes.com/document/ordercustomer-csv-exporter/ but it doesn't seem to export product variations / attributes per order. What I want to do is to make a separate column for each product attributes with their corresponding values in each order's row.

Does anybody have tried it before? Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Vance

Comment: Hi Vance & welcome to WPSE. Your question is on-topic here and you might get lucky that someone with experience with that plugin will see your question, though unlikely. It being a plugin that costs 50 USD - have you asked the woo support for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Vance

I can tell you this is not possible with the stock plugin. I had this same issue on my site. My developer had to edit the plugin code so I could get the meta data in the CSV export. I have a site that deals strictly in personalization so this info is vital.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id where post_type="product"
```

`OR`
[Reference](http://zjstech.com/basic-woocommerce-mysql-queries-for-orders-products-and-categories/)

```
**Please, try this in your workbench or phpMyAdmin if it works**
```

Comment: What does this SQL do and how does it solve the question? Please [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/268813/edit) and add some additional information.

Comment: Is this OK? @Howdy_McGee? I'm new to community so i'm being used to it.

Comment: Welcome! I'm here to help along in this process. For some examples of quality answers, please check out some of the [most voted answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer) - you may also [Take The Tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information. Usually answers are more than just code, they explain what the code does and why the code is useful. For example, you may want to edit your answer and append what this SQL does, what information does it pull, and why a person would want to run this in their PHPMyAdmin.